# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a bunch of problems here. When I run code, it creates a window as should. But when I try to close it, I get "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'children'". Also, when writing text in boxes, text appeares in all three boxes. What am I doing wrong?

```
from Tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.root = Tk()
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()
        self.root.geometry("400x300")
        self.root.mainloop()

    def init_window(self):
        self.root.title("GUI")
        self.ins = StringVar
        self.dele = StringVar
        self.upd = StringVar
        self.b1 = Button(self.root, text='insert(name,info,date)')
        self.b1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.b2 = Button(self.root, text='delete')
        self.b2.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.b3 = Button(self.root, text='update')
        self.b3.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.e1 = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.ins)
        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.e2 = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.dele)
        self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.e3 = Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.upd)
        self.e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
        a = self.e1.get()
        b = self.e2.get()
        c = self.e3.get()

Window()
```

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMaQo.png)

Comment: Please copy and paste the *full traceback* into your question.

Comment: I see some warning signs like `StringVar` not instantiated with `()`, and your project's file being named `TKINTER.py`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of this `Window()` and this `def __init__(self, master=None):` you're not passing in a value so master defaults to None. At the bottom you should have.

```
root = Tk()
Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

And remove `self.root = Tk()`

Full Code for clarification:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        Frame.__init__(self, self.master)
        self.init_window()
        self.master.geometry("400x300")
        self.master.title("GUI")

    def init_window(self):
        self.ins = StringVar
        self.dele = StringVar
        self.upd = StringVar
        self.b1 = Button(self.master, text='insert(name,info,date)')
        self.b1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.b2 = Button(self.master, text='delete')
        self.b2.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.b3 = Button(self.master, text='update')
        self.b3.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.e1 = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.ins)
        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.e2 = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.dele)
        self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.e3 = Entry(self.master, textvariable=self.upd)
        self.e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
        a = self.e1.get()
        b = self.e2.get()
        c = self.e3.get()

root = Tk()
Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code, cleaned up so it runs, but you will have to modify it according to what you want it to do.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Window():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.init_window()
        self.root.geometry("400x300")
        self.root.mainloop()

    def get_values(self):
        print self.e1.get()
        print self.e2.get()
        print self.e3.get()

    def init_window(self):
        self.root.title("GUI")
        self.b1 = Label(self.root, text='insert(name,info,date)')
        self.b1.grid(row=0,column=0)
##        self.b2 = Button(self.root, text='delete')
##        self.b2.grid(row=1, column=0)
##        self.b3 = Button(self.root, text='update')
##        self.b3.grid(row=2, column=0)
        Button(self.root, text="print entry",
               command=self.get_values).grid(row=3, column=0)
        self.e1 = Entry(self.root)
        self.e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.e2 = Entry(self.root, text="info")
        self.e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.e3 = Entry(self.root, text="date")
        self.e3.grid(row=2, column=1)

Window()
```